# GridView Updating on ItemCommand

Tags: vb.net, gridview, itemcommand

i put all my custom "update" code in the RowCommand event, it works fine, but i still get an error from my Data Source

> System.NotSupportedException: Updating
>   is not supported by ObjectDataSource
>   'GetSources' unless the UpdateMethod
>   is specified.

how can i get rid of that error , yes still use my custom update code on the rowcommand?

Comment: I ran into the same issue and the reason I used this methodology instead of declaring the update parameters is because there are thirty of them. I created a business object class that has properties that I populated based on the user's input. The update works fine but I get the same error as you do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the way the ObjectDataSource is intended to be used is you specify the **name of the method** in your custom business object, and it will use reflection to call that method.

So, your page and object might look something like this:

```
<asp:objectdatasource
              id="ObjectDataSource2"
              runat="server"
              updatemethod="MyUpdateMethod"
              typename="MyBusinessObject">
<updateparameters>
<asp:controlparameter name="anID" controlid="DropDownList1" propertyname="SelectedValue" />
</updateparameters>
</asp:objectdatasource>

Public Class MyBusinessObject

    Public Shared Sub MyUpdateMethod(anID As String)
    'data access code
    End Sub 

End Class
```

This pattern of putting control together can be quite productive, but you'll probably feel too restricted after a while.